Efficiently store a dynamic increasing dataset and make computation on it
I want to write a python program that will compute the price of different groceries baskets as their constituants change.
I have a csv file with the constituents of each basket.
PS: a basket can contain another basket
This csv file looks like:
NAME,PRICE

STONE FRUITS,

APRICOT,30

POME FRUITS,

APPLE,10

PEAR,20

FRUITS,

STONE FRUITS,1

POME FRUITS,2  

So FRUITS is a basket containing one basket STONE FRUITS and two baskets POME FRUITS, so FRUITS contains 60 Apricots, 20 apples and 40 pears.
I also have a file with the price of each fruits: Apricot, apple and pear, and I will have to compute the value of each basket, each time the price of one of its constituent changes.
What is the efficient way to store the csv file of groceries baskets in python so that when I recompute the value of the basket STONE FRUITS, it automatically update this value in the basket FRUITS value, considering that the basket FRUITS includes one basket STONE FRUITS?
I was thinking of doing a tree structure using dictionaries in Python, but I don't think it will automatically update a value of a basket STONE FRUITS in every basket containing this basket STONE FRUITS as a constituent. So it will not be efficient as the initial baskets file and each of the basket can be very very big, each of the basket containing hundreds/ thousands of constituents.
Please what will be the best way to efficiently perform the above outcome? What would be the efficient way to dynamically store the csv file containing the groceries baskets?
Thanks in advance.
